# Woocommerce, транслитерация "slug" если "post_title" на иврите

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть проблема в виде большого количества товаров у которых slug соответствует заголовку на иврите.

Вот пример: [https://www.haifa-flower.co.il/bouquets/%d7%96%d7%a8-%d7%90%d7%93%d7%95%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%9f/](https://www.haifa-flower.co.il/bouquets/%D7%96%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F/)

Я написал php обработчик для cron. Он по определенному интервалу проверяет все свежие необработанные ранее продукты и перезаписывает slug.

Проблема в том, что при использовании [Transliterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) на выходе получаю вот такой slug "AAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY".

Есть идеи как реализовать адекватный перевод содержимого $new_slug ?
Чтобы ресурсов кушал как можно меньше.
Например если в магазине 5000 продуктов.

Вот, привожу фрагмент кода обработчика для cron:

```html
<?php

$result = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
    FROM `'.$table_prefix.'posts` as p
    WHERE
        p.post_type = "product" AND
        p.post_status = "publish" AND
        p.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT `product_id`
            FROM `'.$table_prefix.'shop_slug_fix`
            WHERE `product_id` = p.ID
        )
');

if(!empty($result)){
    foreach($result as $product){

        if(!property_exists($product, 'ID') || !property_exists($product, 'post_title') ||
            empty($product->ID) || empty(trim($product->post_title))){
            continue;
        }

        // Set post slug

        $new_slug = $product->post_title; // !!!

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $product->ID;
        $my_post['post_name'] = sanitize_title($new_slug);

        wp_update_post(wp_slash($my_post));

        // Add marker

        $wpdb->query('
            INSERT INTO `'.$table_prefix.'shop_slug_fix`
            SET `product_id` = '.$product->ID.'
        ');

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Возьми cyr-to-lat версии 3,4 и форкни его для иврита https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/cyr2lat/tags/3.4/cyr-to-lat.php

Comment: А это хорошая идея. Спасибо. Спрошу подходит ли нам этот вариант.

Comment: @SeVlad зачем это старьё тащить? Надо взять текущий cyr2lat, там есть таблица на иврите. И поставить его в cron через cli: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/#how%20can%20i%20convert%20many%20posts%2Fterms%20using%20wp-cli%3F

Comment: @KAGGDesign если честно, то я не понимаю нафига вы из простейшего плага раздули такого монстра у которого, к тому же, регулярные проблемы с фронтом/разными плагми  (но это не тут обсуждать). Ну я не знал что в новых есть иврит, а ТСу примера с 3.4 будет достаточно. Тем более что с ним не было проблем (за исключеним одной мелочи - не хватало какого-то сочетания).